# angular project with multiple apps

Tags: angular

Is it possible to run all the apps of an angular multiple apps project ! If yes is there any way to route between those apps .
Example :
I have a an angular project  with app 1 (dashboard 1 : with login and other component) and app2 ( dashboard 2 with login and other component too ) and other index app that help to navigate between the two apps . when user tape 'www.exemple.com' the index app is loaded when he tape 'www.example.com/dashboard1' the app 1 ( dashboard 1 is loaded ) and so on with app tow ( 'www.example.com/dashboard2')
I used this command to create the project

```
ng new my-project --create-application=false
```

and this to create other apps

```
ng generate application app1
```

Comment: Multiple questions here. Yes you should be able to run them all, however, each app needs to run on it’s own port and only app at the time can exist. So for linking between them you’ll need to create links to the specific URL with port. If you need to run multiple angular apps inside the same window that also need to communicate with each other and do not loose context, you might consider Module Federation inside an Nx Monorepo.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the monorepo angular project, you must connect your apps together by routing, when you serve your whole project, angular automatically serve all apps and you can move around your applications by changing route.

I suggest you read this article:

[Monorepo Pattern: Setting up Angular workspace for multiple applications in one single repository](https://kgotgit.medium.com/monorepo-pattern-setting-up-angular-workspace-for-multiple-applications-in-one-single-repository-4e14bc0d0cc0)